# Sonar branch coverage on class declaration

Tags: java, code-coverage, sonarqube

I have a class in Sonar:

```
public class Foo {
..... much code ....
}
```

And Sonar is reporting 1/2 branches covered on that `public class Foo` line.  What does this mean?  How do you test a line which declares a class?

Edit: in case it matters, this is Sonar v3.5.

Edit 2: A screenshot showing what I mean, note the 1/2 beside the "public class" on line 9.  When hovering above this I get a tooltip stating "1 branches are covered by tests"

[image: http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/2626/screenshot20130607at120.png]

Edit #3: Ok, upon a bit more investigation, I've narrowed it down to smallest snippet I can find that triggers this:

```
public class Foo {

    Foo(final String s) {
        assert (s != null);
    }
}
```

If that assert doesn't exist in the constructor, the "N/2 branches covered" flag doesn't get generated in Sonar.  If the assert is gone, then the flag goes away as well.  So my *guess* is that it's based upon the branches within the constructor? (this code has 0/4 branches covered for the assert line, and 0/2 for the public class line).

Comment: A class declaration is not a line to cover. Without a screenshot it would be quite hard to understand and help you.

Comment: Are assertions enabled at runtime?

Comment: Dunno, does the Maven sonar plugin turn on Java assertions?  (ie - I'm gerating this in Sonar by a `mvn sonar:sonar`)

Comment: Do you also confirm that you're using the default Jacoco code coverage engine (and not Cobertura) ?

Comment: Yes, Jacoco, I see `Initializer JacocoMavenInitializer done: 0ms` in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue related to the JaCoCo code coverage component of Sonar.  JaCoCo works on compiled bytecode rather than Java source, and the Java compiler can produce code which is not directly related to the underlying source.

Looking at [the docs](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html) for JaCoCo, there's a section which reads (emphasis added):

> In some situations it is not obvious, why particular lines do have highlighting or have a particular color. The reason is that the underlying code coverage library JaCoCo works on Java class files only. **In some cases the Java compiler creates extra byte code for a particular line of source code**. Such situations might be filtered by future versions of JaCoCo/EclEmma.

Following the link in the passage takes you to the [FilteringOptions](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions) page on the Jacoco's GH site, and it mentions a number of ways in which the JDK can potentially produce code which will will trigger these "spurious" code coverage warnings.

However, that's not what's at play here (or not exactly).

As mentioned JaCoCo works on Java bytecode, so any code which is produced by the compiler that isn't directly attributed to the source will count towards coverage.

In my specific case, I had an `assert` which, in the source, represents a branch at the point where the assert happens, but also at a "global" level.  If you look at the bytecode for the `Foo` class defined above (do a `javap -c Foo`), you'll see:

```
Compiled from "Foo.java"
public class Foo extends java.lang.Object{
static final boolean $assertionsDisabled;

Foo(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   getstatic   #2; //Field $assertionsDisabled:Z
   7:   ifne    22
   10:  aload_1
   11:  ifnonnull   22
   14:  new #3; //class java/lang/AssertionError
   17:  dup
   18:  invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":()V
   21:  athrow
   22:  return

static {};
  Code:
   0:   ldc_w   #5; //class Foo
   3:   invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/Class.desiredAssertionStatus:()Z
   6:   ifne    13
   9:   iconst_1
   10:  goto    14
   13:  iconst_0
   14:  putstatic   #2; //Field $assertionsDisabled:Z
   17:  return
```

Note line 7, which is a conditional branch dependent upon whether or not assertions are enabled.  Thus if you have a class with a plain Java `assert` in it, you'll have this branch somewhere in the bytecode, and this is what produces the "N/2 branches executed" coverage warning on the class declaration, where N is either 0 or 1 depending upon if the class was ever exercised by a test (1) or not (0).

Edit: note that this is also mentioned in https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/eclemma/wiki/FilteringOptions:

> Blocks that throw AssertionErrors - Entire block should be ignored if a condition (if !assertion throw new AssertionError)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue where a utility class was showing class declaration as not covered. (Utility class - Class with all static utility methods). Eventually found out that sonar meant to complain about the default constructor which is implicit, not being covered. Since it is not a custom constructor written in code, sonar showed issue at the class declaration. (May be as written in @Adam Parkin answer, bytecode had implicit constructor at same line as class declaration, not sure)

Since it was utility class we never initialized object of that class in test & hence default constructor not covered. So I added private constructor & issue was resolved. btw sonar had also flagged code smell for private constructor.